# Support for Original Mac Pro 2006

Tags: macintosh

I have a working (yes!) Mac Pro 2006, original release.

Apple stopped offering updates for it ages ago (I got stuck using OSX 10.7.2) and I purchased the latest copy of elementary OS:

1. Burned the image into a USB drive , on another computer
2. Booted
   the machine with the USB (the installer detects it’s as an UEFI
   partition)
3. But I cannot get past the initial screen. It goes
   blank no matter what option

I pass to it

Does anybody had success bringing life to a Mac this old?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To install on a 64-bit Mac that uses a 32-bit EFI you'll have to go [Matt Gadient's website](https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/) and download a slightly modified version of elementary OS 5.1. Burn a DVD if you can, the author strongly suggests it. Give the page a thorough read first.

[Direct download link for the modified iso](https://dedicated.mattgadient.com/linux-mac-iso/elementaryos-5.1-stable.20191202-mac-mattgadient.com.iso) md5: 3ded91fadf4a4a450539d1f9332e72a3

Comment: Thanks a lot, will definitely give it a shot. Will share my findings.